# Turn each row of data into individual line with ggplot

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, line

I'm new to R and to ggplot. I have a dataframe, called "serum",  with both column and row names, like so:

```
               Day.1 Day.2 Day.3  Day.4
Seradigma335  1.2875 1.350 1.850 1.6125
Seradigma322  0.9375 2.400 1.487 1.8125
Sigma         1.1250 1.962 1.237 2.0500
Shapiro red   0.7750 1.575 1.362 1.0125
Shapiro w/red 0.7750 1.837 0.975 0.8250
```

I successfully managed to get a scatter plot using these commands

```
serum["Samples"] = rownames(serum)
serum2 = melt(serum, id=c("Samples"), variable.name = "Day")
ggplot(serum2, aes(x = Day, y= value)) + geom_point()
```

And it looks like this 
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsGF1.jpg)

Which is in the right direction of what I want. The end result I want is each serum to be a separate line. But when I try using [geom_line()](https://imgur.com/a/mkIx3) instead of geom_point() I get vertical lines for each day, instead of the horizontal lines I want for each serum.

Comment: Map your `Samples` variable to an aesthetic.  To get a legend, use `color` or `linetype` or something.  For just connecting the dots for each serum you can use `group`.  So, `aes(x = Day, y = value, group = Samples)`

Comment: might as well include the colour too `aes(x = Day, y= value, group=Samples, colour = Samples)`

Comment: Adding "group = Samples" solved everything!! Thank you!